# Extended Kalman Filter (EKF) singularity problem when I get measurement noise is zero

Tags: matlab, noise, kalman-filter, measurement

My extended kalman filter (EKF) program works well: my estimated state vector is same as real state vector when I give any positive definite number to measurement noise R, even though I gives 10^ -14 to R.

But I want to make covariance analysis, and one part of covariance analysis I need to set zero measurement noise. When I do this, I get singularity warning from `K= (H*P*H'+R)^-1` (kalman gain part of measurement correction part of EKF).

I checked eigenvalues and rank. When I get R=0, some eigenvalues becomes negative a few seconds later and rank is decrease from 15 to 1. When I get R>0, all eigenvalues are positive definite and rank goes to 15 to 7. How can I solve problem, I can not detect cause of this problem.

How could I go about this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: Dont explain what your code is supposedly doing. *Share* the relevant parts of your code with us.

Comment: You are telling the filter that the measurements are perfect, that there is no noise on them. It is therefore not unreasonable that the filter responds by saying it knows the state perfectly too, ie the state covariance matrix is singular. However kalman filters are not able to deal with this, they assume that there is noise on the measurements. Perhaps if you were to explain what you require for 'covariance analysis', someone might be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

I meant initial covariance matrix and process noise matrix are given but measurement matrix is zero to observe effect of measurement noise on total error of estimated covariance matrix. Also, I solved my problem with 2 options. First one is measurement noise should be higher than zero, it can be close to zero. So, Gain is not goes to infinity. Second one is, If H*P*H' part of Gain calculation is close enough to zero, do not make correction on Gain because we do not need to correction on covariance matrix, they very close to each other (prior and posteri) if H*P*H' is zero. Briefly, I solved my problem. Thanks.